# Hoisting variable declarations across script tags?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code inserted into a html file:

```html
<script>
 console.log(myVar);
 var myVar = 1;
</script>
```

After opening this html page in a browser the value of myVar will be undefined.
As far as I understood this is a normal behavior in javascript as first it sets
the memory space and then it executes the code.

Now the weird part is if we split this like this for the same html page:

```html
<script>
 console.log(myVar);
</script>

<script>
 var myVar = 1;
</script>
```

the result will be: Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined

Why?

This is not about variable's scope, it is about hoisting and it seems that hoisting is only inside a javascript block and not available for the whole loaded page in other javascript blocks. The same example here:

```html
<script>
 myFunc();

  function myFunc() {
  console.log('Hello!');
 }
</script>

VS

<script>
 myFunc();
</script>


<script>
 function myFunc() {
  console.log('Hello!');
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer with references for the second point, so I'll defer to someone else. About the first point: that's due to "hoisting".

Answer (score 3):

In the above code the `<script>` with `console.log(myVar)` is rendered first and the system looks for the `myVar` variable in the global and local scope. Since, the variable is not found till this point it raises, `Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined` error as `var myVar = 1;` is rendered in the next `<script>` block.

```html
<script>
  console.log(myVar);
</script>

<script>
  var myVar = 1;
</script>
```

But when you change the order of the `<script>` blocks to something like below then it will work

```html
<script>
  var myVar = 1;
</script>

<script>
   console.log(myVar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because the second script is not considered when the first one runs. The behaviour you describe, declaring all variables first before executing code, applies only to every individual block of code.

Comment: Hi Bergi. I understand your answer. This was also my intuition but I wanted to know why. Javascript never stops to amaze me everyday :) Thanks.

Comment: How else could it work? Consider externally loaded script, where it is much more obvious: the script runs when it is loaded, not some time in the future. I won't wait until all other scripts in the page have been loaded as well. This is clearly necessary when we consider scripts that are dynamically loaded by other scripts.

Comment: Well I thought that hoisting is available for the whole loaded page no matter how many scripts would be run. But it seems that hoisting is available inside a javascript block only.

Answer (score 0):

MyVar is now defined in the scope of your second example (even though it might be in example 1). In your final block of code, myVar is declared.
I highy reccomend reading about variable scope in JavaScript (and Java)