# Wix not reading custom added JS when using custom added HTML

Tags: velo

I am new to wix. I have added custom HTML to a section like so

```
<div id="emptyLegBoard-container-outer">
    <div id="emptyLegBoard-container-inner">
        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;">
            <h1 style="width: fit-content;display: inline-block; color: white"><i style="color: orange"
                                                                                  class="fas fa-plane-departure"
                                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></i>Empty Legs</h1>
            <h1 id="titleMonth" style="display: inline-block;float: right; color: white"></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="emptyLegBoard">
            <table style="width: 100%; overflow: auto">
                <tr id="boardHeadingRow">
                    <td style="width: 15%" class="boardHeadings">DATE</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%" class="boardHeadings">FROM</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%" class="boardHeadings">TO</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%" class="boardHeadings">TIME</td>
                    <td style="width: 25%" class="boardHeadings">PRICE</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="emptyLegBoardInner">

            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>

</div>

      <script>
      window.onload = function(e){ 
renderBoard(); 
}
      </script>
```

then I have added some custom JS and CSS:
Header:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dd348bbd0a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<style>

    i {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

etc
```

Bottom of body:

```
<script>

    function renderBoard() {
        //my js code
        }
</script>

etc...
```

[Custom code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEu7s.png)

when the webpage load the css doesn't seem to be read and in the console I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: renderBoard is not defined"

so my custom code is not been read or my custom html code cannot reach it. Wondering how to fix this issue.

[Custom html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMPFs.png)

Thanks

Comment: If your definition of `renderBoard()` in its own `<script></script>` block appears *after* you call it in a separate block, it’s not going to be in the global `window` scope. It’s not clear how you reached a conclusion otherwise. Soft duplicate of [Hoisting variable declarations across script tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838694/hoisting-variable-declarations-across-script-tags)

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaking, custom code component renders the code inside an iframe which don't have access to the parent window scope.